# Will specifying a SUBTIME interval in MYSQL prevent the query from unnecessarily going through the entire table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Please tell me, if I specify an interval like such: `subtime(now(), INTERVAL 1 day)` inside a MySQL `SELECT` query while having a proper `datetime` column to use as reference - will this prevent from the query to look through the entire table (over 100,000 records in my case) each time it runs but rather look through records made only the past 24 hours? Is `DESC` order needed for the `datetime` table or such? Also, if I have `SUM(column)` in the query, will it also run only for the interval specified?

Edit: If I just would like to use the above mentioned `SUM` to sum a column where there only are integers of value "1" - would it be better to simply check how many rows the `SELECT` query returns with `mysql_num_rows` - is it more efficient in combination with the time interval setting?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you test it?

And how is this related with PHP?

Comment: I have, but can't tell whether or not it indeed stopped after giving me the result I need or went through the entire table as well. Edited for PHP relation, just thought of adding it to the question later...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will in fact prevent MySQL to go through the whole table but not if you just `subtime()` in the SELECT-part. Instead you have to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
WHERE myDateCol BETWEEN DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 day) AND now()
```

The query will now select only rows one day old. Add a B-TREE index on `myDateCol` to speed things up:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD INDEX myIdx USING BTREE (myDateCol)
```

See [MySQL doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-btree-hash.html) on that topic

Comment: Thank you. Could you please take a look at the "Edit" in my question, also what exactly does BTREE do, and do I simply run the `ALTER` query you written in my DB and that's it?

Comment: Do a `SELECT Count(*) FROM myTable WHERE ...` in that case. Dont sum over 1. Btw: 100.000 records is nothing for mySQL and a proper index. BTREE are a Special Kind of index optimized for BETWEEN queries.

Comment: You can check how many rows are examined by MySQL if you do a `EXPLAIN SELECT ... FROM ...`

Comment: I see, but if that table updates all the time - do I need to run the BTREE query in intervals?

Comment: Nope. You just have to set the index on your table. This can be even on an empty table.